# Makefile: count updated object-files

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

Hey is it possible to count all updated files when running make again?
I have a rule `$(NAME)` which is dependent on my Object files which I compile with the rule `%.o : %.c`
So f.e. when my project is already compiled and I change only some files make will only recompile these files and now I need to find a way of counting all these changed `.c` files. Does make have such a feature or is there some workaround?
I need the amount of changed files before I compile not after (which wouldn't be a problem).

Comment: What is the reason you need to count the changed files? What problem is that supposed to solve? Perhaps you should start using a VCS (Version Control System) like Git or similar, to keep track of changes?

Comment: Also please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because your question is one.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I am implementing a progress bar in my Makefile and for that I count the existing object files which completely messes up the progress bar when I run make again when some files changed.

Comment: How do you show the progress bar, do you have a separated program or script? If so, call make with the option `-n` (or `--dry-run` or `--just-print`) and scan its output. All necessary commands are printed, but none is executed. Please [edit] your question and show us a [mre], with emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: There is a simple way to do what you ask, but I don't know whether it will give you what you want.

Comment: "Percent complete" is very hard to do in make.  In order to do it you need (a) how many jobs you have completed, and (b) how many total jobs you will run.  (b) is essentially not possible to determine: make doesn't first figure out how many rules it needs to run, then run them.  It basically runs rules one at a time, following the dependency graph, until suddenly it has no more rules to run, then it's done.  So it never knows how many more jobs to run.